# I want to fetch data of item with id but geeting error for [Route: shop.show] [URI: lord-ganesha-7514796/{id}] [Missing parameter: id]

Tags: php, laravel

"I want to fetch data of item with id  but geeting error saying missing parameter for [Route: shop.show] [URI: lord-ganesha-7514796/{id}] [Missing parameter: id]"

```
My Controller code is
class ECommerceController extends Controller
{
    
  public function index(Request $request)
  {
    $datas = DB::select('select * from ShoppingItems');
    return view('welcome',['datas'=>$datas]);
   

  }

  public function show(Request $request,$id)
  {
    $datas = DB::find($id);
    
    return view('shop.show',['datas'=>$datas]);
  }


 Web Route is

 Route::get('/','App\Http\Controllers\ECommerceController@index')->name('welcome');

 Route::get('/lord-ganesha-7514796/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\ECommerceController@show')->name('shop.show');

welcome.blade.php(dashboard)

<div class="container">
     @foreach ($datas as $data)
     <a href="{{ route('shop.show',['datas'=> $datas])  }}"></a>
      
    <div  class="box1">
        <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/lord-ganesha-7514796.jpg">
        <div class="overlay">
        {{ $data->god_name }}
       </div>
       
    </a> 
         @endforeach
```

Comment: you should be passing an associative array to `route` that has the parameter you want to replace in the url .... `['id' => $data->id]` ... it isn't a view, you don't pass a set of data as a single parameter

Comment: Now this error is occuring what to do Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::find()

Comment: `DB::find($id);` is not a method. `DB::table('whatever')->find($id)` might work, but you could also just use Models, like `Model::find($id)`.

Comment: OK find($id) error is solved my next error is : view[shop] not found is occuring,why it is occuring please provide me some solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited** You need to change array key from datas to id which is defined in your route:

```
<a href="{{ route('shop.show',['id'=> $datas])  }}"></a>
```

Also change DB::find() to this:

```
DB::table('table_name')->find($id);
```

Comment: Yeah it really solved my error but next error is Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::find()

Comment: OK find($id) error is solved my next error is : view[shop] not found is occuring,why it is occuring please provide me some solution

Comment: In the views folder, you should have a shop directory and a show.blade.php file in it (based on your code `view('shop.show',['datas'=>$datas]);`).

Comment: I have this route Route::get('/lord-ganesha-7514796/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\ECommerceController@show')->name('shop');